# Appending Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a for loop where I create numpy array a. I want to have a results numpy array that I append array a to every loop. So the final structure of the results array should be [a,a,a,etc...], such that I can get into a new array [len(a),Len(a),etc..]

I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried np.append, and can't figure out how to do this (I'm confused what the axis parameter does). I'm new to numpy so any help is appreciated. I don't want to flatten the arrays - I want it to behave like appending a python list to a python list.

Sorry about the formatting - I'm on a phone right now.

Comment: Use [hpaulj's non-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48697483/5067311) in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (and quickest) way is to collect the arrays in a list, then use `np.concatenate` to join them all together.

Example test data

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(4,5)
b = np.random.rand(4,5)
c = np.random.rand(4,5)
d = np.random.rand(4,5)

lst = [a,b,c,d]
```

You can concatenate along either axis — by default it is along the 0-axis.

```
>>> result = np.concatenate(lst)
>>> result.shape
(16, 5)
```

...along the 1st axis.

```
>>> result = np.concatenate(lst, axis=1)
>>> result.shape
(4, 20)
```

The arrays need to match in the *other* axis, i.e. if your concatenating them vertically, they must be the same width.